# Copy file from source directory to destination C#

Tags: c#

I would like to copy my files from source folder to my dest. folder

The location / URL(Name of the column in the table) I got it from here GetDataByGeneralRoot();

Now I would like to copy those file from that URL to a new directory.

What I have done is:

```
DataSet1.T_DocumentsDataTable docTab = doc.GetDataByGeneralRoot();

            string gerneralRootPath = docTab.Rows[0]["URL"].ToString();
            gerneralRootPath = gerneralRootPath.Remove(gerneralRootPath.IndexOf("PDF") + 4);

            string datadirectory = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/";
            string final = datadirectory + gerneralRootPath;

            foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(final, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                string t = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
                File.Copy(t, t.Replace(final + t, rootFolderAbsolutePath));

            }
```

My issue / problem is how can I say that I want to get only the files from URL that I got from my method GetDataByGeneralRoot and not all the files what is now happening.

HERE is how my tabel looks like: 
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your source and question but if you are trying to only get the files in the final directory, you need to change SearchOption.AllDirectories to SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly

Comment: @Kell I have a ID and this is linked to some URL and I got this id as well as all the URL/ GetDataByGeneralRoot() and now I would like to copy only files that can be associated with the ID

Comment: In your foreach loop, check whether the file is associated with the ID and if not continue.

Comment: @Kell YES that is more or less what I want to do but how can I do that ?

Comment: How are your files associated with the ID?

Comment: @Kell I just posted a image of my table this is what GetDataByGeneralRoot is getting back

Comment: Replace `foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles("*.*"))` with `foreach (var path in queryResult.Select(q => q.FullPath))`?

Comment: I don't understand that question. Your code currently loops over `*.*` or all files, while you want to loop over the file paths returned from your database query, hence my suggestion. So you have to replace the `*.*` code with code that does something useful with your query result.

Comment: @CodeCaster please dont get me wrong I dont want to insult you or anything but that is my question I am sry for my bad English. but you got the point

Comment: Yes, so what have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well I posted that I dont know how to include the query as you have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
        public void copyAll(DataSet ds, Doc doc, string rootPath, string rootTargetPath)
    {
        ds.T_DocumentsDataTable docTab = doc.GetDataByGeneralRoot();
        string datadirectory = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/";
        string final = datadirectory + rootPath;

        foreach (var row in docTab.Rows)
        {
            var sourceFile = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/" + row["URL"].ToString();
            string targetPath = rootTargetPath + row["URL"].ToString();
            File.Copy(sourceFile, rootTargetPath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `+`, use `Path.Combine()` to combine path elements.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Agreed.

Comment: Thanks allot for you help ! the only issue i have now that rootTargetPath  is a directory, not a file.

Comment: if you use Path.Combine(rootTargetPath, row["URL"].ToString()) you should get a file.